# Facebook Marketing API limits

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I use marketing fb graph API through my fb app with developer level access. I need to basically get all data (info about campaigns, ad sets, stats, and so on) as often as possible. There are some limits and I'm reaching them pretty quickly calling graph marketing API. After a few hundred calls I'm stuck with `err #17 - request limit reached`.

My questions are:

- is it possible and how to increase the limit
- what's the efficient way of getting all data. I'm mostly interested in tracking changes (smth has been added/ updated/ deleted and stats), but first of course I need to gather all my marketing account data somehow.

Comment: to me 'as often as possible' translates to a couple of times a day. is it the same for you? i suppose not so better give all the relevant details. also what's the limit you are hitting? 100000000 req/day? 100 req/hour?

Comment: Thank you @Paolo. Sorry for being inaccurate. Currently on my dev account I hit the cap for around 100 calls which I'm doing one by one. All I do is:
-getting all campaigns (there are 202 of them),  with the limit set up to 25 it's 9 calls,
-trying to get all Ad sets for every single campaign. It just die around 100 calls in total.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

Requesting each object for it's info / stats is going to hurt after a while. If you need detailed stats about engagement, social reach, impressions and such, you have a couple options:

The [`/reportstats` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.4) is available for most objects and overs aggregation filters, specificity, column selecting and other useful things and can also be called to asynchronously generate a stats report for all of the objects you requests. This can even be done on an account level. You could easily retrieve a low-level aggregation of delivery stats for the entire tree of objects in your account or campaign.

Another more recent development in their API is the [Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.4) endpoint, which is a centralized endpoint for retrieving stats as well and operates more like the rest of the graph API (request field names, filtering, preset, etc).

I recommend reading up on each for retrieving delivery stats for your ads api objects.

Additionally, if you're looking for the objects' attributes themselves, there are a couple options. The most useful one may be that you can request the graph api with no endpoint and a list of object ids in the params. The request would look like this `graph.facebook.com/?ids=000000000`. Furthermore, you can use facebook's `fields` query parameter to return attributes about that object. But, wait; there's more. Facebook's graph api offers [field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fieldexpansion) for connected objects through this same query parameter. That is to say, you could request all campaigns' attributes, all ad sets' names and all ad sets' ads' names like so:

```
curl -G \
  -d 'ids=00000000,111111111' \ # ids of campaigns
  -d 'fields=name,adcampaigns.limit(50).fields(name),adgroups.limit(50).fields(name)' \
  -d 'access_token=xxxxxxxxxx' \
  https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I've already figured it out. AFAIR I was using "stats" edge to retrieve some stats with "ids" which doesn't work anymore since v2.4 api was released.
So currently I use "insights" edge and you can provide level (like campaign) to gather stats.
I've managed to deal with #17 error code by switching to diff ad account and going to the cooldown state for 300sec for the account I got it. According to fb documentation for business api after this time the account should be again possible to "spam" with new api calls.
So far it works as POC :)